# Insert only ID while selecting first name and multi query

Tags: java, database

I am trying to insert Appointment of the Doctor while selecting name of the Doctor it will insert ID only in the table database and updating Doctor Availability to 0
here is my code

```
try{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Appointment_Table (Doc_ID, Department_ID, SchedDate, Patient_ID) VALUES\n" +
                     "( (SELECT ID from User_Table where First_Name = ?), (SELECT Department_ID from User_Table WHERE First_Name = ?), ?, (Select Patient_ID from Patient_Records where First_Name = ?));";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        pst.setString(1, (String) DoctorNames.getSelectedItem());
        pst.setString(2, (String) DoctorNames.getSelectedItem());
        String add1 = ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
        String add2 = DoctorTime.getText();
        pst.setString(3, add1+"-/-"+add2+"-PM");
        pst.setString(4, (String) DoctorPatient.getSelectedItem());


        try{
            String sql1 = "Update User_Table set Availability = 0  where First_Name LIKE ?";
            pst = pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            pst.setString(1, (String) DoctorNames.getSelectedItem());
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

Comment: and? does it work?

Comment: no sir i want someone to teach me what is the mistake

Comment: one mistake is you don't tell us what is wrong. we don't know whether you get unexpected functionality, whether you get error messages/stacktraces, we don't know whether the problem is compile or runtime, ...

Comment: sorry about that sir the error is java.sql.SQLException: query does not return results i just want to insert to Appointment_Table that contains only Appointment_ID,Doc_ID,Dep_ID,Patient_ID.. how can i insert only ID without inserting ID in the frame? just only the doc name dep name and patient_name

Answer (score 0):

try to add **LIMIT 0,1** after **SELECT** just like this:

```
INSERT INTO Appointment_Table (Doc_ID, Department_ID, SchedDate, Patient_ID) VALUES 
( (SELECT ID from User_Table where First_Name = ? LIMIT 0,1 ), (SELECT Department_ID from User_Table WHERE First_Name = ? LIMIT 0,1 ), ?, (Select Patient_ID from Patient_Records where First_Name = ? LIMIT 0,1 ));
```

it is for MySql DBMS for SQL Server use Top 1 keyword

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID from User_Table where First_Name = ?
```

Comment: Good day sir i am just wondering if it is possible to put 3 data in one jComboBox example is i have user_Table with First_Name, MI, Lastname and select it and put it into jcombobox

Answer (score 0):

add 3 combo box to your form one for  Doc_ID  and one for Department_ID  and another one for Patient_ID

make this class

```
class ComboItem
{
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public ComboItem(String key, String value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public String getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Add the ComboItem to your comboBox.

```
comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("doctor name ", "Doc_ID"));
comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("doctor 2 name ", "Doc_ID 2"));
comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("doctor 3 name ", "Doc_ID 3"));
```

Whenever you get the selected item.

```
Object item = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
String value = ((ComboItem)item).getValue();
```

the edit your SQL

```
INSERT INTO Appointment_Table (Doc_ID, Department_ID, SchedDate, Patient_ID) VALUES (combo_Doc_ID_value,combo_Department_ID_value,?,combo_Patient_ID_value)
```

Comment: i dont know what to do sir i am just a really beginner as in a beginner

Comment: just make ComboItem class use  my code and  set and get data  jus like i mentioned before each combo take 2 value first one is visible it is the doctor name second one is  doctor ID it is not visable in GUI but when you select combo you can get  ID  and name

Comment: Is there any thing i can do in the class you given  ? Should i edit something or not and i try to put the combobox.additem(new ComboItem...... And it gives me error and where should i put it ? And the object item = combox..... ? Where should i put this code? I am very sorry that i dont understand your code i am just a beginner i really need this for my Thesis on October 1 thank you for your help reply please

Comment: bro add me in face book i will fix  it for you by teamviewer 
https://www.facebook.com/safen.muhamad